# url rewrite rule for urls that contain // in them

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Ive got a bit of an issue with a site that is indexed with Google. The SEO people have pointed out that the domain has been indexed with double // at the end of the domain portion and is causing duplicate records in Google. We have checked all the server side components and all appears to be configured correctly.

example

www.domainname.com//shop/products

this renders quite nicely on screen, but the SEO guys are reporting that this is an issue.

```
RewriteRule ^//(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

is a rule we have applied, but there appears to be no change in the browser, it still generates as www.domainname.com//shop/products

We are using the Helicon Ape product for the rewrites but just wondering if this should be visible to the user on screen or is this handled on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R,L]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, this however causes an infinite loop on the redirects.